# Change network used by cluster traffic types with powershell

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

I was reading this [technet blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2011/06/17/10176338.aspx) about Windows HA cluster traffic types.

It explains how to change the metrics of cluster traffic types with the cmdlets, but for settings like “Allow cluster network communication on this network” it refers you to the GUI console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ClusterNetwork` returns an interactive ClusterNetwork object that you can modify directly.

What the default output doesn't show you is the property called `Role`. This is the property that controls the options listed in the GUI, and it can have one of three possible integer values:

- `1`: Allow cluster network communication on this network

  - `3`: Allow clients to connect through this network
- `0`: Do not allow cluster network communication on this network

To allow cluster network communication, but not client connections:

```
$MyNetwork = Get-ClusterNetwork "MyHeartbeatNetwork"
$MyNetwork.Role = 1
```

This works equally well in Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012 and 2012 R2, and is not restricted to PowerShell 3.0